# MySQL Trigger error: logging trigger is not populating the log table

Tags: mysql

I created the below trigger in MySql script which is a logging trigger and populates a  table removed_trades_log when an entry is deleted from trades table.

```
DELIMITER //            
CREATE TRIGGER log_data AFTER DELETE 
ON trades FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO removed_trades_log
    VALUES
      (old.trade_id,now())
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I delete an entry from the table trades, it is not adding an entry in the removed_trades_log

```
DELETE FROM  trades 
where trade_id = 'T1008'
```

removed_trades_log is still empty after this running this command.

Though it gave successful message when I deleted the entry from trades table, the log table is still empty. I am thinking the trigger is not attached yet with the table trades, but I cant figure out where to put it?

Comment: You are missing a terminator after the insert statement so the trigger does not syntax..

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger has a syntax error. Here is the corrected Trigger

```
DELIMITER //            
CREATE TRIGGER log_data AFTER DELETE 
ON trades FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO removed_trades_log
    VALUES
      (old.trade_id,NOW());
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

now create the trigger and test it. It should work.

Comment: 'should work ' ?